# Why does equality not appear to be a symmetric relation in Python?

Tags: python, syntax-error, comparison-operators

I'm learning about comparison operators, and I was playing around with True and False statements. I ran the following code in the Python shell:

```
not(5>7) == True
```

As expected, this returned `True`. However, I then ran the following code:

```
True == not(5>7)
```

and there was a syntax error. Why was this? If the first line of code is valid syntax, then surely the second line of code should also be valid. Where have I gone wrong?

(To give a bit of background, my understanding is that `=` in Python is only used for variable assignment, while `==` is closely related to the mathematical symbol '='.)

Comment: I haven't figured this one out. I the python shell, `not(5>7) == 100` is also `True`.

Comment: @tdelany `100` is `!= 0` so it compares as truthy

Comment: @PatrickArtner - only in something looking for a boolean comparison like `if`. `True == 100` is `False`. Since 50 and 100 are both truthy, would `50 == 100` be true?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864156/why-in-python-does-0-0-0-0-equal-0-false

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The syntax error seems to be caused by the `not` keyword, not (pun intended) the equality operator:

```
True == not (5 > 7)
# SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

```
True == (not (5 > 7))
# True
```

The explanation can be found in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not):

> `not` has a lower priority than non-Boolean operators, so `not a == b` is interpreted as `not (a == b)`, and `a == not b` is a syntax error.

Basically, the interpreter thinks you're comparing `True` to `not`.

Comment: Right, so `not(5>7) == True` boils down to `not(False) == True` (no problem here), whereas `True == not(5>7)` boils down to `True == not(False)`, and because `True` and `not` are adjacent to each other, the problem which you have described occurs. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: True == not(5 > 7) boils down to (True == not) (False), in which case the first statement obviously makes no sense.

Comment: Ok, thank you. This was a very insightful answer.

Comment: To expand a bit on this or make it more explicit: `not` is an operator (similar to a unary `-` operator), not a function like `abs` as `not(...)` seems to imply. The brackets are not required for the `not` itself and they are only necessary if you want to enforce the order in which operators are evaluated. @Joe

Comment: @Joe: `not(5>7) == True` boils down to `not (False == True)`. `not` is not a function, and the parentheses and lack of spacing in `not(5>7)` are misleading. This kind of confusion is one of the primary reasons not to treat keywords as if they were functions.